# Programmatically detect if Mouse and Keyboard are plugged in

Tags: vb.net, windows, keyboard, mouse

I was wanting to know what is the best way to detect if a mouse or keyboard is plugged in to the computer? I have an application that is mostly used in a touchscreen standalone but I want to know if there is a keyboard plugged in don't fire off pulling up the windows keyboard or a form that contains a numeric keypad. Then change some behavior if the mouse is plugged in against if it isn't.

Comment: Not something I've ever tried to do, but [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/51477/How-to-Get-a-List-of-Non-Working-Devices-Using-VB) maybe useful, maybe you could do something using this to find a mouse/keyboard. Not sure though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using VB.Net, I would use `System.Management` (don't forget to add this reference in the Project [Menu] -> Add Reference) `ManagementObjectSearcher` combined with `System.Linq` to find the solution like this,

```
Imports System
Imports System.Management
Imports System.Linq

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine(HasDevice("PointingDevice"))
        Console.WriteLine(HasDevice("Keyboard"))
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

    Public Function HasDevice(strtype As String)
        Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher("root\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_" + strtype)
        Dim result = From mobj In searcher.Get()
                     Select mobj Where mobj("Status").ToString() = 0
        Return Not IsNothing(result)
    End Function    
End Module
```

Result

[image]

You could also hard-coded it to avoid input mistake like TRiNE suggested (though using C#)

```
Public Function HasPointingDevice()
    Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher("root\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_PointingDevice")
    Dim result = From mobj In searcher.Get()
                 Select mobj Where mobj("Status").ToString() = 0
    Return Not IsNothing(result)
End Function

Public Function HasKeyboard()
    Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher("root\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_Keyboard")
    Dim result = From mobj In searcher.Get()
                 Select mobj Where mobj("Status").ToString() = 0
    Return Not IsNothing(result)
End Function
```

And call them like this

```
Public Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine(HasPointingDevice())
    Console.WriteLine(HasKeyboard())
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

They will produce the same result

Answer (score 2):

You can use C# `System.Management` and `ManagementObjectSearcher`

Here is a sample code. Modify as it matches your need.

```
    public bool isPointingDeviceAttached()
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
            new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_PointingDevice");

        int devCount = 0;

        foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get()) {
            if(obj["Status"].ToString().Contains("OK")) // if device is ready
            devCount++;
        }
        return devCount>0;
    }

    public bool isKeyboardAttached()
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
            new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_Keyboard");

        int devCount = 0;

        foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get()) {
            if (obj["Status"].ToString().Contains("OK")) // if device is ready
                devCount++;
        }

        return devCount>0;
    }
```

Make sure to add `using System.Management;` line and to add `System.Management` in references.
You can use more ManagementObject attributes as match your need. Here is a list of attributes and some other external references.

[Pointing device class ref. & attribute list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394356(v=vs.85).aspx)

[C#, C++ similar example](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/377776/Keyboard-Mouse-Status)

Answer (score 0):

I spent a couple of days tackling this and found nothing that says a keyboard is detached. Only what is attached currently. That gave me an idea though! With my keyboard attached I checked and three keyboard devices were listed. I removed the keyboard and one disappeared. Now I just look for obj.tostring.contains("USB") and if it doesn't I know there is no keyboard attached to my tablet.

The other two were HID and ACPI which I guess are the touchscreen and mousepad.

Of course other tablets may be different so it isn't a robust
Edit: TO be clear, using the previous answer's code     `foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get()) { if (obj["Status"].ToString().Contains("OK")) // if device is ready devCount++;`
I use obj.tostring.contains("USB") instead of (obj["Status"]xxxx If the tablet is plugged in I will get three keyboards listed and all the "Status" variables report OK. If I unplug the keyboard there are only two entries both of which have a status of OK while the USB keyboard status simply isn't there. So I just look for the USB string in the object and if it isn't there then I know it isn't plugged in.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).